# is it possible to filter the content of .xsession-errors?

Tags: linux, bash, xorg

Most users .xsession-errors file grows because gtk and other librarys give silly error messages.

Is there a way to reduce silly error messages but have a usefull .xsession-errors file?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible.
This solution has been tested with Debian jessie and `wdm` as login-manager.

Multiple steps are required to do:
**Steps 8 to 10 are `wdm` specific and might look different for `gdm` or `kdm`**

1. log in as root
2. open file `/etc/X11/Xsession` in editor
3. replace first line in file 
   `#!/bin/sh`
    with
   `#!/bin/bash`
4. locate line `ERRFILE=$HOME/.xsession-errors` and add below the line `ERRFILTER=$HOME/.xsession-errors_filter`
5. locate line `exec >>"$ERRFILE" 2>&1` and replace it with
   `if [ -f $ERRFILTER ]; then
   exec > >(stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 grep -v -f "$ERRFILTER" >>"$ERRFILE") 2>&1
   else
   exec >>"$ERRFILE" 2>&1
   fi`
6. save file and exit editor
7. create a file .xsession-errors_filter in your home directory and write there keywords from error messages you do *not* want to see. Only one keyword / phrase per line is permitted.
8. open file /etc/X11/wdm/Xsession
9. locate line `. /etc/X11/Xsession` and replace it with `exec /etc/X11/Xsession`
10. save file
11. double check if everything is correct because X11 might not start otherwise
12. logout and login into X

**some explanation:**

- we need bash for this time of redirecting therefor the replacement of /bin/sh and the change from `.` (source) to exec
- then we use *inverted* `grep` for filtering. `grep` is reading filter keywords from file '.xsession-errors_filter'
- stdbuf disables the buffering with grep, so error messages get written instantly to the file
- `exec > >()` redirects all output from the shell to a subshell (which runs grep)